# Serial communication between GPS and Arduino Ethernet

Tags: softwareserial, gps

I'm trying to read out GPS positions from a serial GPS module I have.

I'm using an Arduino Ethernet and a Haicom HI-204 III GPS (http://www.haicom.com.tw/driver/hi-204iii_usb.pdf).

If I connect the GPS directly to my computer (through a USB-serial converter) at 4800 baud, 8N1, I receive a nice stream of position and diagnostics messages:

```
$GPGGA,183652.000,5702.0870,N,00954.4732,E,1,06,2.0,20.5,M,42.5,M,,0000*62
$GPGSA,A,3,22,08,27,18,11,32,,,,,,,3.4,2.0,2.7*37
$GPRMC,183652.000,A,5702.0870,N,00954.4732,E,0.00,,310518,,,A*70
$GPGGA,183653.000,5702.0870,N,00954.4732,E,1,06,2.0,20.5,M,42.5,M,,0000*63
$GPGSA,A,3,22,08,27,18,11,32,,,,,,,3.4,2.0,2.7*37
$GPRMC,183653.000,A,5702.0870,N,00954.4732,E,0.00,,310518,,,A*71
$GPGGA,183654.000,5702.0870,N,00954.4732,E,1,06,2.0,20.5,M,42.5,M,,0000*64
$GPGSA,A,3,22,08,27,18,11,32,,,,,,,3.4,2.0,2.7*37
$GPGSV,3,1,12,08,67,204,28,18,59,267,23,10,47,067,26,11,46,279,32*72
$GPGSV,3,2,12,27,36,156,30,01,33,270,20,32,31,116,32,28,26,314,18*79
$GPGSV,3,3,12,22,21,217,33,14,15,140,24,20,09,055,,24,04,038,*7D
$GPRMC,183654.000,A,5702.0870,N,00954.4732,E,0.00,,310518,,,A*76
$GPGGA,183655.000,5702.0870,N,00954.4732,E,1,06,2.0,20.5,M,42.5,M,,0000*65
$GPGSA,A,3,22,08,27,18,11,32,,,,,,,3.4,2.0,2.7*37
$GPRMC,183655.000,A,5702.0870,N,00954.4732,E,0.00,,310518,,,A*77
$GPGGA,183656.000,5702.0870,N,00954.4732,E,1,06,2.0,20.5,M,42.5,M,,0000*66
```

Now I'm trying to read these messages from the Arduino. But when I connect the GPS to a SoftwareSerial port, I only get gibberish:

> :⸮⸮J2⸮⸮>>⸮

(note that when I copy/paste the output to here, many of the charaters disappear, so they are probably completely invalid)

My code looks like this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define rxPin 3
#define txPin 4

SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(rxPin, txPin); // RX, TX

void setup (){
  Serial.begin(4800);
  gpsSerial.begin(4800);
}

void loop (){
  while (gpsSerial.available()) {
    char c = gpsSerial.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }
}
```

In think the output looks like wrong serial settings, but I have tested all speeds (and verified that 4800 baud works through the serial adapter), and as far as I can tell, SoftwareSerial is 8N1 by default.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What USB adaptor are you using?

Comment: The GPS unit you link to is a USB device, not a serial device. How can you be connecting that through a USB to serial converter?

Comment: Good question :-) The USB unit simply becomes USB because they have a serial to USB-converter on the cable between the GPS and the USB plug. So I cut the cable on the serial side of the converter and connected that to the Arduino.

Comment: So you don't actually have any information about the electrical signalling the unit uses? You need an oscilloscope to examine the signal - see if it's TTL or EIA-232 signalling.  If it's the latter you will need to feed it through a MAX232 first.

Comment: Further Googling leads me to the theory that I might need a RS232-to-TTL converter between the GPS and the Arduino. I'm not sure, though, as I supply the GPS with 5 V directly from the Arduino, so there should be no need for a step down from 12 V.

Comment: It's not just stepping down - it's inverting and removing the negative voltages.

Comment: Ah, you're too quick :-) No, I don't have any further information, and unfortunately also no scope available. So I guess I will test a MAX232 (somebody also suggests that here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=9798.0)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that info. I'll try it and check back in when I get hold of the hardware. Thanks again!